# How to align matrix on columns in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, columns

I want to align 6 matrices on two columns/3lines, with 2 matrices/line. Both columns to be aligned left. Can someone give me a hint or something?

Comment: In order to help you better it is often better to add the .tex code to understand what you want. Can you visit this link, please? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Use the `align`  environment with two columns of aligned material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking at an environment `align` nested in a `fleqn` environment, as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
& A_{11}  =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
& A_{12}  =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \\
& A_{21}  =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
& A_{22}  =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \\
& A_{31}  =\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
& A_{32}  =\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope it is what you are looking for.

Romain

Comment: Why `fleqn`? Just `align*` would do.