# Align two equations in two lines

Tags: equations, align

I have these equations on different lines and I would like you to align them all where the "=" is.

```
\begin{align*}\label{eq:Karodebc}
&x=0, &P=P_{in}\\
&x=0,    &  \frac{dP}{dx} =-\frac{3}{2} \frac{\mu}{h^3W}Q_i,
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327707/250119 . Should be easy.

Comment: (or [math mode - How to align matrix on columns in LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431935/how-to-align-matrix-on-columns-in-latex) .)

Comment: [Here are some options](https://pastebin.com/raw/1g3MbBBv).